# Adding a new element to an array in the json object java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am writing automation script to validate json responses of REST APIs and i am using faster xml to serialize and convert java object to json format.
I have a user case where I have to get the json response and add a new array element to an existing array and post it back.
The json response after GET looks like this :

```
{
   "name":"test",
   "id":"1234",
   "nodes":[
            {
                "nodeId":"node1"
            },
            {
                 "nodeId":"node2"
            }
    ]
}
```

To this json response, I need to add a third entry for nodes array
`{ "nodeId": "node3" }` and then post this.

Can someone please help me understand how to add a new array element to an existing array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go for cleaner approach, create Object with below structure -

```
public class Response{
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private List<Node> nodes;
   <Getter & Setter>
}
public class Node{
   private String nodeId;
}
```

1. Serialize the json -

> Response response = objectMapper.readValue(responseJson,
>   Response.class);

2. Add the new incoming node object to `response` -

> response.getNodes().add(New Node("{new node Value}"));

3. Deserialize before post -

> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response);

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
//Your JSON response will be in this format
String response = "{ \"name\":\"test\", \"id\":\"1234\", \"nodes\":[ { \"nodeId\":\"node1\" }, { \"nodeId\":\"node2\" } ] }";
   try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray nodesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("nodes");
        JSONObject newEntry = new JSONObject();
        newEntry.put("nodeId","node3");
        nodesArray.put(newEntry);
        jsonResponse.put("nodes",nodesArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now you can post your `jsonResponse.toString()` as required.